# QoS Settings for ZXDSL 831CII

Tags: qos, adsl-router

i have ZXDSL 831CII and i want to configure QoS on it.

This is screenshot of QoS settings page and possible values for each drop down are written as well.

Please help me to configure it so that the priority will be ...

1. VOIP ( only gtlak and skype )
2. Web Browsing
3. Bittorrent and all other things

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What type of VoIP? VoIP by itself can mean a lot of things and doesn't tell us what protocol/ports you'll be using for it.

Comment: Thanks @MaQleod for your response, i mean gtlak and skype by VIOP if i am wrong.